# Android Studio errors when running application

Tags: android, android-studio

I am a complete beginner in Android development using Android Studio. Whenever I try running an application on Android Studio, I get some errors. Please refer to the screenshot below for the errors. Could someone please tell me what I should do to remove this error?

[image: Android Studio Error]

Comment: Have you turned on `Offline mode` in Settings > Build > Gradle?

Comment: you are in offline mode. Settings, search for `offline`, uncheck the checkbox

Comment: Yes, I have turned that on. @KNeerajLal

Comment: @njzk2 You mean, I should turn off offline mode?

Comment: Make sure you are connected to the internet, turn off `Offline mode` and try again.

Comment: I tried doing that, but still getting the same error. Is it something to do with JUnit? @KNeerajLal

Answer (score 0):

testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

remove this from build.gradle

from

dependencies {